# Problem with custom font in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, css, static-resources, font

I am trying to apply a custom font to my visualforce page. I followed the steps laid out in Use Custom Fonts . I have no idea what's wrong.

Here's my css definition:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SenticoSansDT;
  src: url({!URLFOR($Resource.SalsaFonts, '/SenticoSansDT.woff')});
  src: url('/resource/SenticoSansDT.woff') format('woff');
}
```

In css i added :

```
  font-family: SenticoSansDT,sans-serif; !important
```

But it doesn't work. In network resources i got 404
[image]

[image]

Font is uploaded to StaticResource as .zip :

[image]

Zip looks like that:

[image]

Comment: can you check SenticoSansDT.woff this file name is available in that zip?

Comment: all zip contents are on last image

Comment: then you are accessing this "SenticoSansDT.woff " in your CSS but that file is not even there in that zip contents file name should match.

Comment: Is that issue fixed? am facing same issue